# Woocommerce Client order email - Encoding issue in hebrew

Tags: php, wordpress, encoding, utf-8, woocommerce

I moved a site server and upgraded to woocoommerce; since then, I have had an issue with emails to client (New order, Note added to order):

If Hebrew letters/words appear in the email, they show up as question marks. Before the changes they used show up in Hebrew with no problems.
Emails the admin gets about new order, inventory, ETC, and all the site, Hebrew appears with no problem.

The email looks like this:

> Your order has been received and is now being processed. Your order
>   details are shown below for your reference:
>       ??????:
>       ?? ??? ?????? ?? ?????? ???? ???? ????? ??????
>       ????? ?????: 312700
>       ????: 783 ??? ??????
>       ?”? ???? ????.
>
> ```
> ?????? ?????? ?? ????? ?? ??? + ???? ?????. ??? ????? ?? ???? ?????? ??? 2045 ?????? , ????? “???? 2045″.
> ?? ?? ??? ???? ????? ?? ?????? ????? ????? ???.
> * ?????? ?? ???? ?? ??????? ?????.
> * ????? ??????? ?? ????? ??? ??? ?????, ?????? ????? ????????
> *?????? ??? ????? ??? 3 ??? ?????
>
>  ???? ?????
>  StoreName
>  Our Bank Details
>  ???? ???? - ??????
>
>  Account Number: 879878
>  Sort Code: ???? 989
>
>  Order #2656
>  Product  Quantity    Price
>  ???? ???????? ????? ?? OFRA   1  ₪170.00
>  Cart Subtotal:   ₪170.00
>  Shipping:    ????? ????
>  Payment Method:  ????? ??????
>  Order Total:     ₪170.00
>  Your details
>
>  Email: email@gmail.com
>
>  Tel: 90809
>  Billing address
>
>  ???????? ??????
>  ?????
>  ?????
>  09809
>
>  Shipping address
>
>  ???????? ??????
>  ?????
>  ?????
>  09809
> ```

When the site set to Hebrew, all of the email is `?????? ??? ????` (except numbers); I set it to English to be sure it's not just a translation problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: batz are you able to share your site's url?

Comment: P.s. I installed another fresh installion on different domain on the server, and same problem. I guess its something doing with the server. The question is what exactly.

Answer (score 0):

batz try opening `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/emails/class-wc-email.php`, look for this piece of code:

```
/**
 * get_headers function.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_headers() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_headers', "Content-Type: " . $this->get_content_type() . "\r\n", $this->id, $this->object );
}
```

And change it to this:

```
/**
 * get_headers function.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function get_headers() {
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_headers', "Content-Type: " . $this->get_content_type() . "; charset=UTF-8\r\n", $this->id, $this->object );
}
```

Comment: Checked it, same problem. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

batz I'm sorry I'm not quite able to test my answers, so I still can't guarantee that they'll work. It's going to be tricky to trace down the exact reason for this bug.

So far I've found out that unfortunately WooCommerce emails do not support right-to-left scripts, so even if we get the correct glyphs to show, you might still be experiencing some issues. But it's worth a try.

#### Method 1

In your theme's `functions.php` file add this piece of code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_email_header', 'add_css_to_email');

function add_css_to_email() {
echo '
<style type="text/css">
* {
    font-family: sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
';
}
```

#### Method 2

If Method 1 doesn't work, try going to `Dashboard > WooCommerce > Settings > Emails`, then select one by one all the emails, and change `Email Type` from `HTML` to `Plain text`. This might not be an ideal solution for you, but it can:

1. help us track down the root of the problem - please let me know if changing emails to plain text helped or not;
2. at least make the text visible.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the help. method 2 works. Methos 1 not works. but i need the html option to work. If you want to test live, i set up a domain on the server with installation of word-press and woo, has the same problem. address: shulchani dot com. To access admin if you want user: admin , pass: 123456 . You could change there whatever you like, its only test domain.